# Globally Published Workflow only available for Parent/base content type and not the children

Tags: 2010, workflow, content-type

I've published a globally reusable workflow which is associated with a parent or base content type.

Within one of my subsites I have a library full of documents that are child content types of this parent. My workflow does not appear as an available workflow for those documents. However if I (temporarily) permit documents of the parent content type to be added to the list then the workflow is available.

In SPD when I look at the child content types I see my workflow listed in the associated workflows box.

Should this work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered my mistake.

When you associate the workflow to a content type it is very important that you select the copy of the workflow from the 'globally reusable workflow' list and not the identical one on the 'reusable workflow' list.